# Training, validation and testing without using caret

Tags: r, validation, testing, training-data

I'm having doubts during the hyperparameters tune step. I think I might be making some confusion.

I split my dataset into training (70%), validation (15%) and testing (15%). Below is the code used for regression with Random Forest.

**1. Training**

I perform the initial training with the dataset, as follows:

```
rf_model <- ranger(y ~.,
                   date = train ,
                   num.trees = 500,
                   mtry = 5,
                   min.node.size = 100,
                   importance = "impurity")
```

I get the R squared and the RMSE using the actual and predicted data from the training set.

```
pred_rf <- predict(rf_model,train)
pred_rf <- data.frame(pred = pred_rf, obs = train$y)
RMSE_rf <- RMSE(pred_rf$pred, pred_rf$obs)
R2_rf   <- (color(pred_rf$pred, pred_rf$obs)) ^2
```

**2. Parameter optimization**

Using a parameter grid, the best model is chosen based on performance.

```
hyper_grid <- expand.grid(mtry = seq(3, 12, by = 4),
                          sample_size = c(0.5,1),
                          min.node.size = seq(20, 500, by = 100),
                          MSE = as.numeric(NA),
                          R2 = as.numeric(NA),
                          OOB_RMSE = as.numeric(NA)
)
```

And I perform the search for the best model according to the smallest OOB error, for example.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(hyper_grid)) {
  model <- ranger(formula = y ~ .,
                  date = train,
                  num.trees = 500,
                  mtry = hyper_grid$mtry[i],
                  sample.fraction = hyper_grid$sample_size[i],
                  min.node.size = hyper_grid$min.node.size[i],
                  importance = "impurity",
                  replace = TRUE,
                  oob.error = TRUE,
                  verbose = TRUE
  )           

  hyper_grid$OOB_RMSE[i] <- sqrt(model$prediction.error)    
  hyper_grid[i, "MSE"] <- model$prediction.error
  hyper_grid[i, "R2"] <- model$r.squared
  hyper_grid[i, "OOB_RMSE"] <- sqrt(model$prediction.error)
}
```

Choose the best performing model

```
x <- hyper_grid[which.min(hyper_grid$OOB_RMSE), ]
```

The final model:

```
rf_fit_model <- ranger(formula = y ~ .,
                       date = train,
                       num.trees = 100,
                       mtry = x$mtry,
                       sample.fraction = x$sample_size,
                       min.node.size = x$min.node.size,
                       oob.error = TRUE,
                       verbose = TRUE,
                       importance = "impurity"
)
```

Perform model prediction with validation data

```
rf_predict_val <- predict(rf_fit_model, validation)
rf_predict_val <- as.data.frame(rf_predict_val[1])
names(rf_predict_val) <- "pred"
rf_predict_val <- data.frame(pred = rf_predict_val, obs = validation$y)
RMSE_rf_fit <- RMSE rf_predict_val$pred, rf_predict_val$obs)
R2_rf_fit <- (cor(rf_predict_val$pred, rf_predict_val$obs)) ^ 2
```

Well, now I wonder if I should replicate the model evaluation with the test data.

The fact is that the validation data is being used only as a "test" and is not effectively helping to validate the model.

I've used cross validation in other methods, but I'd like to do it more manually. One of the reasons is that the CV via caret is very slow.

I'm in the right way?

Code using Caret, but very slow:

```
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", 
                     repeats = 10)

grid <- expand.grid(interaction.depth = seq(1, 7, by = 2),
                    n.trees = 1000,
                    shrinkage = c(0.01,0.1),
                    n.minobsinnode = 50)

gbmTune <- train(y ~ ., data = train,
                 method = "gbm",
                 tuneGrid = grid,
                 verbose = TRUE,
                 trControl = ctrl)
```

Comment: Asking for the best modeling strategy is an opinion request. Not really a “how to program question “

Comment: yes and no, because I'm afraid of being wrong

Comment: What does that have to do with anything?

Comment: Everything ! As I didn't find similar questions, I think the code might be structured wrong. Not in terms of strategy, but machine learning method direction.